# what is the sql syntax to use when trying to start a slave replication instance of mysql server

Tags: mysql

A MySql instance is not replicating from master to slave after running SQL commands to initialize one as slave and the other as master

Im trying to setup a mysql replication slave, but when i run the below sql commands even though it seems its been configured as a slave, replication from the master is not getting to it, see sql command

```
CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO SOURCE_HOST='MyIPAddress,
SOURCE_USER='MyUsername',
SOURCE_PASSWORD='Mypassword',
SOURCE_LOG_FILE='',
SOURCE_LOG_POS=4;
START REPLICA
```

Comment: For one thing, you didn't specify a log file.

Comment: the log file is specified in the reproduction instance and specifying it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Toss these

```
SOURCE_LOG_FILE='',
SOURCE_LOG_POS=4;
```

Do you have the privilege `REPLICATION_SLAVE` on `MyUsername`?  (It is the only privilege needed for the Replica.)

For further discussion, please provide

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;  -- on Primary 

SHOW SLAVE STATUS;  -- on Replica
```

Comment: privilege replication was setup on the master using this command GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'myusername'@'%';